# How to use two different memcache instances on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, memcached

I am storing database query results in memcache on heroku. I am using [memcachier](http://memcachier.com) addon on heroku. For example if I have a cache User's tasks in memcache. I do something like this:

```
 def cached_tasks
   Rails.cache.fetch([:users, id, :tasks], :expires_in => 12.hours) { tasks.to_a }  
 end
```

This works perfectly fine but I want to use two different memcache instances to store data.

**Why?**

One that is used very frequently, basically data changes frequently and another for those which are big data objects and those will never change or very rarely.

How can I use two different instances and specify that cached_tasks should be stored in memcache_instance_1 and other like cached_images should be stored in memcache_instance_2

**Why not to use the same one:**

Because sometimes I need to flush the whole cache and that will flush the big data too which I don't want to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not serve the big-rarely-changing as static assets?

Comment: did you see above comment?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Yes. But those things are user specific and every day I am getting somewhere around 400-500 new users and thats there data like their fb friends list etc. Check accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare three new `env` variables for your heroku app

```
BIG_MEMCACHIER_SERVERS
BIG_MEMCACHIER_USERNAME
BIG_MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD
```

Add a file called `big_cache.rb` in the `config\initializers` directory:

```
module Rails
  def self.big_cache
    @big_cache ||= ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore.new(
      (ENV["BIG_MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"] || "").split(","),
      :username => ENV["BIG_MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
      :password => ENV["BIG_MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"])
  end
end
```

Now you can access the 2nd cache as follows:

```
Rails.big_cache.fetch(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is to try and define what from the the things i am caching is actually something that requires cache, or it actually needs some life-limited persistency.

I would leave the Rails internal caching system to do what it does best: page, action and fragment caching, and use another persistency engine (such as Redis) to hold and maintain those large objects you talked about (implementation of this suggestion is a completely different question).

note that Redis also allows setting a TTL (time to live) on keys - so it can provide this life limited persistency that you want.